# Linux Mint with AMDGPU, Monitors drop signal after Mint boot animation

Tags: linux, x11, login

I installed Linux Mint MATE 19.1 and installed the AMD MESA 18.x+ drivers as shown in the Wiki (adding ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa and upgrading). Here are my specs/setup:

Make/Model: Dell PowerEdge R810 (Generation I)

Graphics Card: AMD Radeon Pro WX 3100

Linux Mint Version: Tried both 18.3 and 19.1, with no success

Connection:

- 1 DisplayPort to Monitor 1
- 2 Mini-DisplayPort cables to Monitors 2 and 3

After I installed MESA drivers from the PPA above, I notice that all of my monitors show the Linux Mint startup logo and animation but as soon as my login manager (the default, lightdm) starts (I have auto-login enabled), my monitors all drop signal and it falls back to the VGA output on my server. The displays work perfectly in Windows Server with Windows AMD drivers installed, so this isn't an issue with the display cables or monitors themselves. And oddly, whenever I shut down all 3 monitors work as well. So it seems the graphics card is just not working when the display manager is on.

I am able to use the default VGA output of the server after the boot animation for Linux Mint but not through any of the outputs through the graphics card. Here are the steps I tried to alleviate my problem:

- Checked Kernel parameters, nomodeset is not set, vga= is also not set
- Ensured my Kernel is at least 4.10
- Tried adding the GPU settings to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/05-graphics.conf manually
- Checked blacklist list, AMDGPU is not blacklisted and neither is radeon (only amd76x_edac is there, which I believe is unrelated)
- Tried blacklisting mgag200, which is default driver for VGA port in case it is messing with AMDGPU (which made VGA also stop working with X, so I removed that)
- Tried reinstalling Xorg
- Tried both Linux Mint MATE 19.1 and Linux Mate Cinnamon 18.3

Here are the outputs of a few commands for debugging what's happening:

$ lsmod | grep amd

```
amdkfd                180224  1amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfdamdgpu               2703360  1chash                  16384  1 amdgpui2c_algo_bit           16384  2 mgag200,amdgputtm                   106496  2 mgag200,amdgpudrm_kms_helper        167936  2 mgag200,amdgpudrm                   401408  7 mgag200,amdgpu,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

$ dmesg | grep amd

```
amdkfd                180224  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
amdgpu               2703360  1
chash                  16384  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 mgag200,amdgpu
ttm                   106496  2 mgag200,amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 mgag200,amdgpu
drm                   401408  7 mgag200,amdgpu,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

$ lspci -knn | grep -A3

```
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100] [1002:6985]
    Subsystem: Dell Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100] [1028:0b0c]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

### Kernel modules: amdgpu

10:03.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200eW WPCM450 [102b:0532] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Dell MGA G200eW WPCM450 [1028:02d4]
    Kernel driver in use: mgag200
    Kernel modules: mgag200

$ inxi -G

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100] vendor: Dell driver: amdgpu 
  v: kernel bus ID: 08:00.0 
  Device-2: Matrox Systems MGA G200eW WPCM450 vendor: Dell driver: mgag200 
  v: kernel bus ID: 10:03.0 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: amdgpu,ati,fbdev,vesa 
  unloaded: modesetting resolution: 1280x960~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0 128 bits) 
  v: 3.3 Mesa 18.3.3 - padoka PPA direct render: Yes
```

$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[    23.200]
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[    23.201] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    23.201] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-138-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    23.201] Current Operating System: Linux server 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64
[    23.201] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=HIDDEN ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    23.201] Build Date: 25 October 2018  04:11:27PM
[    23.201] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    23.201] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    23.201]     Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    23.201] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    23.201] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Mar  4 07:53:21 2019
[    23.201] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    23.201] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    23.201] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    23.201] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    23.201] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[    23.201] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    23.201] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    23.201] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    23.201] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    23.201] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    23.202] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    23.202] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    23.202]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.202] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    23.202]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.202] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    23.202]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.202] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    23.202]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.202] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    23.202]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.202] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    23.202] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    23.202] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    23.202] (II) Loader magic: 0x55eff6484020
[    23.202] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    23.202]     X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    23.202]     X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    23.202]     X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    23.202]     X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    23.203] (++) using VT number 7

[    23.203] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    23.205] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    23.251] (--) PCI: (0:8:0:0) 1002:6985:1028:0b0c rev 0, Mem @ 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xefe00000/2097152, 0xfb280000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000ec00/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    23.251] (--) PCI:*(0:16:3:0) 102b:0532:1028:02d4 rev 10, Mem @ 0xf0000000/8388608, 0xfaffc000/16384, 0xfa000000/8388608, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    23.251] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    23.251] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    23.252] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.252]     compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.252]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    23.252] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card0
[    23.252]     loading driver: amdgpu
[    23.253] (==) Matched amdgpu as autoconfigured driver 0
[    23.253] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    23.253] (==) Matched mga as autoconfigured driver 2
[    23.253] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    23.253] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    23.253] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 5
[    23.253] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    23.253] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    23.253] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    23.253] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.253]     compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 18.0.1
[    23.253]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.253]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.253] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    23.253] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    23.253] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.253]     compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 18.0.1
[    23.254]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.254]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.282] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
[    23.283] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mga
[    23.283] (II) UnloadModule: "mga"
[    23.283] (II) Unloading mga
[    23.283] (EE) Failed to load module "mga" (module does not exist, 0)
[    23.283] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    23.283] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    23.283] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.283]     compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
[    23.283]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.283]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.283] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    23.284] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    23.284] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.284]     compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[    23.284]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.284]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.284] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    23.284] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    23.284] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.284]     compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[    23.284]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.285]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.285] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card0
[    23.285]     loading driver: amdgpu
[    23.285] (==) Matched amdgpu as autoconfigured driver 0
[    23.285] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    23.285] (==) Matched mga as autoconfigured driver 2
[    23.285] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    23.285] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    23.285] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 5
[    23.285] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    23.285] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    23.285] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    23.285] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.285]     compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 18.0.1
[    23.285]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.285]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.285] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    23.285] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    23.286] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.286]     compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 18.0.1
[    23.286]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.286]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.286] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
[    23.286] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mga
[    23.286] (II) UnloadModule: "mga"
[    23.286] (II) Unloading mga
[    23.286] (EE) Failed to load module "mga" (module does not exist, 0)
[    23.286] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    23.286] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    23.287] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.287]     compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
[    23.287]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.287]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.287] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    23.287] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    23.287] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    23.287] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    23.287] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    23.287] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.287]     compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[    23.287]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.287]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.287] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    23.287] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    23.287] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    23.287] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    23.287] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    23.287] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.288]     compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[    23.288]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.288]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.288] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    23.288] (II) Unloading vesa
[    23.288] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    23.288] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[    23.288] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    23.288] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    23.288] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    23.299] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    23.316] (II) modeset(1): using default device
[    23.316] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    23.316] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    23.316] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    23.316] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.316]     compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
[    23.316]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.316] (**) FBDEV(2): claimed PCI slot 16@0:3:0
[    23.316] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[    23.316] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    23.316] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    23.333] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    23.333] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    23.333] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    23.333] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[    23.333] (EE)
[    23.333] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    23.333] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    23.333] (EE)
[    23.350] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

$ sudo lshw -c display

  `*-display

       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:40 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:efe00000-efffffff ioport:ec00(size=256) memory:fb280000-fb2bffff memory:fb2c0000-fb2dffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: MGA G200eW WPCM450
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:10:03.0
       version: 0a
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=mgag200 latency=64 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16
       resources: irq:19 memory:f0000000-f07fffff memory:faffc000-faffffff memory:fa000000-fa7fffff memory:c0000-dffff`

As you can see the monitors aren't even getting detected by X11.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you add `mgag200.modeset=0` to the GRUB boot line, which worked better for me than blacklisting mgag200. This solution was provided to me in https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/132035/fedora-28-server-install-failure/ and came from https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=783783